# vw width set of div but for some reason they don't align

Tags: html, css

I try to build a page with a complex div arrangement,

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LOTti.png)

The divs should have a total width of 90.3vw, and I try to arrange them with 1px border in mind.

for some weird reason the last div in the last row sticks out (SOMETIMES, especially when I adjust the window size), despite the sum of the widths of the divs in the last row being 90.3vw.

here is a jsfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/dg5r8kfh/2/

here is the html:

```css
.bo {border:1px solid black;position:absolute;color:black;word-wrap: break-word;overflow:hidden;}
.f1 {width:25.7vw;}
.f2 {width:25.2vw;}
.f3 {width:14.2vw;}
.f4 {width:39.4vw;padding-right:1px;}
.gg {height:14mm;}
.g1 {width:4.7vw;margin:0;padding:0;}
.g2 {width:11.9vw;}
.g3 {width:64.3vw;}


.l {height:36mm;}
.m {height:30mm;}
.st {height:15mm;}
.s {height:calc(15mm - 1px);}
.xs {height:calc(6mm - 1px);}
.fl {float:left;}

.lp1 {left:4.7vw;}
.lp2 {left:calc(30.4vw + 1px);}
.lp3 {left:calc(55.6vw + 2px);}
.lp4 {left:calc(80.8vw + 3px);}
.lp5 {left:calc(9.4vw + 1px);}
.lp6 {left:calc(14.1vw + 2px);}
.lp7 {left:calc(26vw + 3px);}
.lp8 {left:calc(90.2vw + 4px);}

.tp1 {top:calc(10mm + 0px);}
.tp2 {top:calc(40mm + 1px);}
.tp3 {top:calc(25mm + 1px);}
.tp4 {top:calc(46mm + 1px);}

.tp5 {top:calc(52mm + 1px);}

.pl {padding-left:3px;}
.desc {font-size:8pt;margin-top:1mm;}
  .desc2 {font-size:8pt;}
.cont {font-size:16pt;font-weight:bold;}
.hi {margin-top:-8pt;}

.d_s2   {width:5.3vw;}
.c_s2   {width:19.1vw;}

.fl {float:left;}

.rot {transform: rotate(270deg);}
```

```html
  <div class="f1 l bo lp1 tp1">
    x1
  </div>
<div class="f2 m bo lp2 tp1">
    x2
  </div>
<div class="f2 xs bo lp2 tp2">
    >x3
  </div>
<div class="f2 m bo lp3 tp1">
    y
  </div>
<div class="f2 xs bo lp3 tp2">
    x5
  </div>
<div class="f3 st bo lp4 tp1">
    x6
  </div>
<div class="f3 s bo lp4 tp3">
    x7
  </div>
<div class="f3 xs bo lp4 tp2">
    x8
  </div>
<div class="f1 xs bo lp1 tp4">
    x9></div>
<div class="f2 xs bo lp2 tp4">
    x10&nbsp;
  </div>
<div class="f4 xs bo lp3 tp4">
    <p class="desc pl">x11</p>
  </div>

<div class="gg g1 bo lp1 tp5 of">
  <p class="rot">x12</p>
</div>

<div class="gg g1 bo lp5 tp5">
  <p class="rot">x13</p>
</div>

<div class="gg g2 bo lp6 tp5">
  <p class="desc pl">x14</p>
</div>

<div class="gg g3 bo lp7 tp5">
  <p class="desc pl">x15</p>
</div>

<div class="gg g1 bo lp8 tp5 mal">x16
</div>
```

is there something I am missing, can I fix this problem, or should I arrange my CSS differently (and if yes, how?)

Answer (score 1):

I looked at the code but could not find what was causing the problem. Nevertheless, I think that you should consider using a CSS grid approach instead of utility classes for this kind of complex layout. I took the liberty of creating a basic working example that accomplish the same visual layout in a simpler and cleaner way, in the hope that it might be exactly what you want and need, even if you were not aware of it when you asked the question in the first place.

```css
.parent {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(4, 1fr) repeat(2, 4fr) repeat(2, 1fr);
  grid-template-rows: repeat(2, 3fr) repeat(2, 1fr) 2fr;
  grid-column-gap: 1px;
  grid-row-gap: 1px;
  width: 90.3vw;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

.parent>div {
  box-shadow: 0 0 0 1px red;
}

.div1 {
  grid-area: 1 / 1 / 4 / 5;
}

.div2 {
  grid-area: 1 / 5 / 3 / 6;
}

.div3 {
  grid-area: 1 / 6 / 3 / 7;
}

.div4 {
  grid-area: 1 / 7 / 2 / 9;
}

.div5 {
  grid-area: 2 / 7 / 3 / 9;
}

.div6 {
  grid-area: 3 / 5 / 4 / 6;
}

.div7 {
  grid-area: 3 / 6 / 4 / 7;
}

.div8 {
  grid-area: 3 / 7 / 4 / 9;
}

.div9 {
  grid-area: 4 / 1 / 5 / 5;
}

.div10 {
  grid-area: 4 / 5 / 5 / 6;
}

.div11 {
  grid-area: 4 / 6 / 5 / 9;
}

.div12 {
  grid-area: 5 / 1 / 6 / 2;
}

.div13 {
  grid-area: 5 / 2 / 6 / 3;
}

.div14 {
  grid-area: 5 / 3 / 6 / 4;
}

.div15 {
  grid-area: 5 / 4 / 6 / 8;
}

.div16 {
  grid-area: 5 / 8 / 6 / 9;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  <div class="div1">1</div>
  <div class="div2">2</div>
  <div class="div3">3</div>
  <div class="div4">4</div>
  <div class="div5">5</div>
  <div class="div6">6</div>
  <div class="div7">7</div>
  <div class="div8">8</div>
  <div class="div9">9</div>
  <div class="div10">10</div>
  <div class="div11">11</div>
  <div class="div12">12</div>
  <div class="div13">13</div>
  <div class="div14">14</div>
  <div class="div15">15</div>
  <div class="div16">16</div>
</div>
```

Comment: is there a way to set the grid heights in mm and the width in vw?